# CSS loves some code but not all?

Tags: html, css

I know that's not exactly what's happening, but it feels that way. Essentially I'm having a CSS style sheet that feels as though the page is accepting some of it but just deciding some of it isn't worthy. I know it's something I'm doing, I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to save my life.

In this area it doesn't appear to be rounding the bottom corners as it should:

HTML:

```
<table class="header">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8"><img src="img/logobar.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
   <td><a href="index.html" class="white">Home</a></td>
   <td><a href="index.html" class="white">...long list, same formatting</a>  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.header {
  width: 722px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}

tr.blue {
  background: linear-gradient(#2C8ECF, #1969B4);
  font-size: 8px;
}

a:link.white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited.white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here it's displaying the text as white on white:

HTML:

```
<table class="links">
  <tr><td class="black">Watch this space for upcomming events!<br></td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.links {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}

td.black {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

There is no general body formatting or default table formatting.

I'm not entirely sure if these are both part of one general thing I'm doing horribly, horribly wrong or if they're two separate issues. I'm a newcomer when it comes to HTML/CSS.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: when it comes to tables, the css rules are not the same as in other elements.i believe thats is the problem in your case, i suggest you search for table css stylings.

Comment: Be sure that you have properly closed all tags. If you put too many /td or /tr it can screw with your format.  If your code is exactly what you're using then I see in the first table two consecutive </td> tags

Comment: Be sure you don't have another CSS rules that are conflicting or overriding these rules. Is this ALL of your CSS?

Comment: It's working just fine, also your 2nd problem.

Comment: Css is **cascading** that means code further down overwrites code higher up. Also more specific code overwrites less specific code as in **body p {** is less specific than **body div table p {** and so on. Make sure none of your code overwrites itself and also use spaces when listing selectors:  table .Header instead of table.Header

Answer (score 2):

It is rounding just fine you just needed a border on the table 1. Please check the snippet, I just added a red border and code is working fine

```css
table.Header {
width: 722px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

tr.blue {
background: linear-gradient(#2C8ECF, #1969B4);
font-size: 8px;
}

a:link.white {
color: white;
font-size: 8pt;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited.white {
color: white;
font-size: 8pt;
text-decoration: none;
}

table.Links {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #D6D6D6;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 10px;
color: black;
font-size: 12px;
}

td.black {
color: black;
padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="Header">
<tr>
<td colspan=8><img src="img/logobar.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="blue">
<td><a href="index.html" class="white">Home</a></td>
<td><a href="index.html" class="white">...long list, same formatting</a>    
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="Links">
<tr><td class="black">Watch this space for upcomming events!<br></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from joyBlanks is technically ok, but is ugly.  If you give the same properties of border-radius to the appropriate elements of the table you can make it look better and have all the roundness you desire.

Here is the modified snippet:

```css
table.Header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
tr.blue {
  background: linear-gradient(#2C8ECF, #1969B4);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
tr.blue > td {
  padding: 10px;
}
tr.blue > td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}
tr.blue > td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
a:link.white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited.white {
  color: white;
  font-size: 8pt;
  text-decoration: none;
}
table.Links {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #D6D6D6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
td.black {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table cla`ss=` "Header">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=8>
      <img height="80" width="auto" src="http://www.google.com.ec/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
    <td><a href="index.html" class="white">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="index.html" class="white">...long list, same formatting</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="Links">
  <tr>
    <td class="black">Watch this space for upcomming events!
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```